# Use one class from two different namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a problem with some legacy code that resides in one namespace. call it A. Then in a new project we started from scratch and put all code in a different namespace. Call it B.

Now some of the code from A was moved to B at the start of the project and recently we have realized that we need to use lots more of the legacy code than we wanted in order to meet deadlines.

My problem is now that I have a class Foo that resides in both namespace A and B. This is OK and naturally compiles fine.

However, at the borders of the new and the legacy code there are some of those classes that now are duplicated that we need to be the same. Otherwise it's hard to pass data between the new and the legacy code.

The new code accesses Foo using B::Foo and the legacy code accesses it with A::Foo or only Foo and a using directive in some places.

What I want is for A::Foo, B::Foo or Foo to point to the same implementation (the B::Foo version). Is this possible? The public interface of both Foo classes are of course identical.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
namespace B {
    class Foo { /* ... */ };
}

namespace A {
    using B::Foo;
}
```

Comment: looked promising but I get error C2874: using-declaration causes a multiple declaration of 'B::Foo'

Comment: @tkarls well you'd have to remove the `A::Foo` class.

Comment: well I have. A::Foo's cpp file isn't in the project and A::Foo's header is only including B's file and then the:namespace A {
    using B::Foo;
}